# Can Julia's GLM do weighted least squares?

Tags: julia, glm

I'd like to run weighted least squares regression. The documentation for the GLM package seems to allude to this being an option, but I can't figure out exactly what the syntax should be.

```
test = DataFrames.DataFrame(x = float([1:12]), y = randn(12), w)
lm(y~x, test)
```

Suppose I wanted to weight each observation by some weighting vector

I tried

```
fit(LinearModel, y~x, data, wts=[rep(.5,6), rep(.7,6)])
```

but it's not able to find a matching method.

Are there any documents with more examples of how to use the GLM package?

Comment: Using your `test` `DataFrame`, does `glm(y ~ x,test, Normal(), IdentityLink(), wts=[rep(.5,6), rep(.5,6)])` give your desired fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @rickhg12hs had it right:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> using GLM

julia> test = DataFrames.DataFrame(x = float([1:12]), y = randn(12));

julia> glm(y ~ x,test, Normal(), IdentityLink(), wts=[rep(.5,6), rep(.2,6)])
DataFrames.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel{GLM.GlmResp{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.Normal,GLM.IdentityLink},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64}},Float64}:

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.715555  0.506611 1.41243   0.1578
x            -0.137865 0.0827818 -1.6654   0.0958


julia> glm(y ~ x,test, Normal(), IdentityLink(), wts=[rep(.5,6), rep(.7,6)])
DataFrames.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel{GLM.GlmResp{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.Normal,GLM.IdentityLink},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64}},Float64}:

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.914117   0.59612 1.53345   0.1252
x            -0.187296 0.0765347 -2.4472   0.0144
```

Comment: Fortunately, `glm(y ~ x, test, Normal(), IdentityLink(), wts=ones(length(test[:y])))` and `lm(y ~ x, test)` produce the same results.